# Set dynamic default values for SPO list with custom new form

Tags: column, url, spo

I have a SP Online list with custom new form.

I want to update default values for 3 columns dynamically using the URL and make the columns ready only.

For Eg, I have the below URL:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/GeorgeTest/Lists/Actions/new.aspx?Title=George&Continent=Asia&Country=India
```

Using this URL, i want to set the value of "Title" column as "George", "Continent" as "Asia" and "Country" as "India"

Right now, this URL, sets the value of Title column as George but Continent and Country column values are not set.

How to make it working?

Please Note: The URL is generated from another list and the column value varies for every user.

Comment: What is the data type of Continent and Country columns? How you are setting Title field?

Comment: Continent is choice and Country is Single Line of Text

Comment: How are you setting the Title field? using javascript? Can you please add code to your question?

Comment: No,I havent written any script. if i just access the URL which i have updated in my query, I could see the Title column being value with the value given.

Comment: There must be something used on custom list form to set the title field from URL. How you have customized the list form?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I havent done anything on the custom list form.If there are anyways to achieve it, kindly let me know